# Symfony remember me not working

Tags: php, symfony

I have symfony 3.4 app, and i use security as my authentication system. Works great, but remember me not working. If i open browser, check remember me and login, all is ok, but when i close my browser and open again, my session is clear. I must login again :(

My security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: phone
    firewalls:
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            logout_on_user_change: true
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: /diary/list
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout: true
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Default controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
        }
        return $this->render('base.html.twig');
    }
}
```

User entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="phone", message="Phone already taken")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array($this->role);
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $phone
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->phone,
            $this->isActive,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->phone,
            $this->isActive,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong :( My app code https://github.com/PawelCyrklaf/diary

Comment: Have you tried disabling `logout_on_user_change` in your firewall? Maybe your user contains some information that make it look like it changed and that's why you are being logged out. Please also check your logs for any `security` related messages.

Comment: I check this today :) video in my apps     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-_0EfFpWzA&feature=youtu.be no work

Comment: I set logout_on_user_change to false, app still no work :( not remember me